# How to apply the height dynamically to the last div based on the different screen resolutions in angular 8

Tags: angular, responsive-design

I'm working on a angular enterprise application where I have Sidebar on the left and content in the right side. Content container have Text contents in the top and the table or so dynamic contents needs to display below to it. So I need to set the dynamic height to the div that minus the "header part" and the "text content" above to the div that needs to fix the dynamic height.

I tried the work around in my ts file like

```
public pageHeight = (window.screen.height) - 324;

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
  this.pageHeight = event.target.innerHeight - 224;
}
```

and in my template file I'm using like

```
(window:resize)="onResize($event)" [style.height.px]=pageHeight
```

It's working but the height not working as expected in all screen resolutions. The alignment of the container is not fixed at the bottom of the screen as expected. In this code the static height value of 324 must be dynamic. But I'm calculating manually by adjusting the value in **Dev console** and using for height calculation. I'm stuck to get the dynamic value instead of calculating 'px' value manually.

Attaching herewith the image for better understanding and what I'm expecting. Appreciating your guidance on this might save my time to solve this issue.

[image]

Comment: This could all be achieved using css only. Are the heights for header and div01 fixed height?

Answer (score 0):

If the solution does not have to be strictly in JS/TS, then you can set the height of that element with CSS ([Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) or [Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout))

Answer (score 0):

Can't you get around this by adding a wrapper around `content div 01` and `content div 02`, having it's height equal to `calc(100vh - <header-height> - <page-padding-if-any>)` . And then just use `flexbox` so the `divs` get auto-sized?

Also, if the `text content` has a predefined height, it's even easier. Just set the `dynamic content's contaiener height` to `height: calc(100vh - <header-height> - <text-content-height> - <page-padding-if-any>`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.grid-container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'header header' 'sidebar content';
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
.header {
  grid-area: header;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
.sidebar, .content > div {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.content {
  grid-area: content;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content .second-div {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="header">
    This is header
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    This is sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>This is div 1</div>
    <div class="second-div">
      This is sparta
      <hr>
      <div style="border: 1px solid #ccc; min-height: 100px;" contenteditable>
         Click here to edit (and make it taller)...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

A few notes:

- tweak the sizes to fit your needs (i.e. sidebar width can be a percentage if you don't want `px`)
- to see how it currently performs with a lot of content in `.second-div`, uncomment the commented div inside it.
- if you want to move the scrollbar from `.content` to the entire page, replace `height: 100vh` on `.grid-container` with `min-height: 100vh`.
- in case it's not obvious, all `background`, `border`, `padding` rules are not part of the solution, you can safely remove them. The important bit is the part related to sizes and `display:grid` related props.

That's about it.

Obviously, you can have a `@media` query overriding any of the above on narrower devices. If you have trouble with it, define your requirement and I might have a go at it.

***Note***: I haven't used JavaScript not because it's not possible, but because you don't need it. Whenever you can achieve stuff with CSS, don't use JS. You'll end up killing performance. Especially in Angular, where things can go south quickly if you set up too many observables.

***Another note:*** Your layout is likely more cumbersome than what I demoed here. If you create a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in codesandbox.io or similar, re-creating your layout exactly, I can help out with the specific CSS rules to make it work as this demo (it's just a case of using the proper selectors and making sure it's scoped properly - so it applies).